# Elapsed Time for Minutes and Seconds Not Working

Tags: vb.net, datetime, timer

I am trying to measure Elapsed Time using VB.net and NetFramwork > 4.0 and a Timer control

I set a time stamp with these two line of code when a button is clicked it is not inside the Timer

```
lapTimeS = CInt(DateTime.Now.ToString("ss"))
lapTimeM = CInt(DateTime.Now.ToString("mm"))
```

I also tried only using the lapTimeS to only get the total sec and did some division
This does not work see the code posted below

The issue is if I start at 2 min before the hour will say 12 noon and the timer runs for 3 min
The min value is incorrect

Code to display results that is inside the Timer

```
    lapTimeES = CInt(DateTime.Now.ToString("ss"))
    lapTimeEM = CInt(DateTime.Now.ToString("mm"))

    If btnB1.Visible = False And btnB2.Visible = False And btnB3.Visible = False And btnB4.Visible = False _
    And btnB5.Visible = False And btnB6.Visible = False And btnB7.Visible = False And btnB8.Visible = False _
    And btnB9.Visible = False Then
        pbOne.Top = 300
        PbT.Visible = False
        tbAns.Visible = True
        'Tried This
        'Q = totalSec / 60
        'R = totalSec Mod 60

        Q = Math.Abs(lapTimeEM - lapTimeM)
        R = Math.Abs(lapTimeES - lapTimeS)
        tbAns.Text = Q & " Min" & " " & R & " Sec"


        count = 0
        tmrMove.Stop()
```

The Game in this case should not run longer than 3 to 6 min and near impossible to complete it in less than 60 sec
So I could not see the value in measuring hours

Should I only capture sec and convert to Quotient and Remainder?
OR do I need to combine mm and ss in one capture statement and subtract the complementary elapsed statement?
If I need to capture Hours then how do I only display Min & Sec Results?
Please this is not 3 question it is mostly me asking what direction to take

Comment: Any particular reason for not using [Stopwatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch)?

Comment: @Martheen NO other than I started with the Timer control which is running other methods SO can the Stopwatch Class or Method run in sync with the Timer thread Looking at the link Do I need to stop my Timer method to use this Class ?

Comment: I don't get about the "sync with the thread". If you mean to have it available on both where you start and measure it, just declare the stopwatch as a class member.

Comment: Your edit about stopping is even more confusing. Why do you need to stop the timer to use which class (your class? stopwatch?). Stopwatch doesn't care about what are you doing in other thread.

Comment: @Martheen OK let me try that I have never declared a Class Member I assume I do this inside the Timer Method OR just add a Class inside a Class ? Sorry for the confusion the code in the link had a stop and start Jumping to conclusions by BAD thanks for the link

Comment: Nah, by class member I mean declare it as a member of your current class, most likely your Form1 or whatever you name your current Form. You can even set it to public if other forms need it too.

Comment: @Martheen Worked Great Now I just need to EDIT the Dim elapsedTime As String to only reflect Minuets and Seconds Sure that is possible Thanks

Comment: @Martheen Working great BIG help I am not much of a gamer so learning new concepts is enjoyable with expert advice

Comment: `lapTimeES = CInt(DateTime.Now.ToString("ss"))` Instead of back and forth from date to string to integer just `lapTimeES = DateTime.Now.Second`

Comment: @Mary Thanks I agree my code was way imperfect If you look at the link Martheen shared I am having an issue the first time it runs but the second time it is cumulative time I tried stopWatch.Restart BIG issue is where to put the code I have a btnStart that says stopWatch.Start and in the Timer I placed the stopWatch.Stop when condition is met Time is a Pain when you do not know what you are doing and so many old Posts

Comment: @Mary Got it just need stopWatch.Reset() DUH look at the properties